# What type of algorithm should I use for forecasting with only very little historic data?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, forecasting

The problem is as follows: 
I want to use a forecasting algorithm to predict heat demand of a not further specified household during the next 24 hours with a time resolution of only a few minutes within the next three or four hours and lower resolution within the following hours.

The algorithm should be adaptive and learn over time. I do not have much historic data since in the beginning I want the algorithm to be able to be used in different occasions. I only have very basic input like the assumed yearly heat demand and current outside temperature and time to begin with. So, it will be quite general and unprecise at the beginning but learn from its Errors over time.

The algorithm is asked to be implemented in Matlab if possible.

Does anyone know an apporach or an algortihm designed to predict sensible values after a short time by learning and adapting to current incoming data?

Answer (score 1):

Well, this question is quite broad as essentially any algorithm for forcasting or data assimilation could do this task in principle.

The classic approach I would look into first would be Kalman filtering, which is a quite general approach at least once its generalizations to ensemble Filters etc. are taken into account (This is also implementable in MATLAB easily).
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter

However the more important part than the actual inference algorithm is typically the design of the model you fit to your data. For your scenario you could start with a simple prediction from past values and add daily rhythms, influences of outside temperature etc. The more (correct) information you put into your model a priori the better your model should be at prediction.

For the full mathematical analysis of this type of problem I can recommend this book: https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9781107706804

Answer (score 0):

In order to turn this into a calibration problem, we need:

- a model that predicts the heat demand depending on inputs and parameters,
- observations of the heat demand.

Calibrating this model means tuning the parameters so that the model best predicts the heat demand.

If you go for Python, I suggest to use OpenTURNS, which provides several data assimilation methods, e.g. Kalman filtering (also called [BLUE](https://openturns.github.io/openturns/master/theory/data_analysis/gaussian_calibration.html#linear-gaussian-calibration-bayesian-blue)):

https://openturns.github.io/openturns/latest/user_manual/calibration.html